# Why does the pH decrease, when adding pancreatin to different types of milk (cow milk, soy milk etc.)?

Tags: homework, enzymes, experiment, ph

I'm experimentally observing how pancreatin affects the pH in different types of milk.
**Why does the milk's pH decrease when I add an enzyme solution to different types of milk** (e.g., cow milk, soy milk etc.)**?**
I am not sure how to explain this reaction.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). "*Homework*" is interpreted to mean any academic or other assignment, test preparation, or task given in relation to a class, educational setting, or self-learning.

Comment: @Chris This is more of an experiment than homework.

Comment: From no-view a homework question. As well  Seeks visualization of what could actually going on there in chemical scale, which may require expertise on respective fields.

Comment: I have edited your question, removing the word level after pH. Also named the enzyme mixture in the title to make it specific, although this pancreatic preparation is so crude it hardly deserves a name.

Comment: Isn't it something to do with making cheese? That's what upsets vegetarians? Is it the same as the renet reaction? Try googling that.

Answer (score 1):

the pancreatic fluid contains lipase which breaks down the fat in the milk in to fatty acids and glycerol. The fatty acids produce lower and create a more acidic pH.

Comment: Please don't answer questions when others have flagged lack of effort on the part of the poster. It is clearly a homework question, so that if she used your answer she would be getting undeserved credit. Fortunately the fact that she did not respond to the original comments suggests her deadline is long past and she has no further interest in the question. Which is why I would ban all homework questions if I had my way.

Comment: @David Which I'm glad you don't because some people don't have a teacher they can ask and the answer might not be in their textbook!

Comment: Please add some references! :)

Comment: @L.B. — l recognize my view is not list policy, and meta would be the place to discuss this, but there is no reason for not drawing attention to the characteristics of many homework posts.

Comment: @David There is that. And also I don't appreciate blatant homework questions. Just making the point that there are people like me who have questions regarding homework (and are either self studying or homeschooled and so don't have a teacher) who are afraid to ask for fear of a downvote and therefore, loosing reputation.

Comment: @L.B. — OK. I'll try to be more tolerant in future.